# 'No overload matches this call' when trying to return a Map

Tags: typescript, dictionary

When trying to create a Map I receive a strange error that I don't quite understand:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [string, number]>): Map<string, number>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(string | number)[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [string, number]>'.
      The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'IteratorResult<(string | number)[], any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [string, number], any>'.
```

In my code, I am taking in an array and trying to construct a map object of it

```
function createMapOfHeadersToIndex(headers: string[]): Map<string, number> {
  const headersWithIndex =
      headers.map(header => [header, Number(headers.indexOf(header))]);
  return new Map(headersWithIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `headersWithIndex`, the compiler *inferred* its type for you, based on heuristic rules about what people tend to do with arrays:

```
const headersWithIndex =
  headers.map(header => [header, Number(headers.indexOf(header))]);
// const headersWithIndex: (string | number)[][]
```

That type, `(string | number)[][]` means "an array of arrays of `string` or `number` elements".  That's not an incorrect description of `headersWithIndex`, and in other circumstances it would be a reasonable guess about what kinds of things you're likely to do with it:

```
headersWithIndex.push([1, "two", 3, "four"]); // okay
```

Unfortunately, that type is not specific enough to be accepted by the `Map` constructor, which expects an iterable whose elements are explicitly a 2-[tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of a key followed by a value.  And so the construct call fails, because the compiler has forgotten anything about the particular ordering and length of the arrays inside the `headersWithIndex` elements.

---

The most straightforward way to fix this is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) when you are creating the array literal containing the key and value:

```
const headersWithIndex =
  headers.map(header => [header, Number(headers.indexOf(header))] as const);
// const headersWithIndex: (readonly [string, number])[]
return new Map(headersWithIndex); //okay
```

That `as const` gives the compiler a hint that you'd like it to infer something like the most specific type it can; it's almost like saying "I'm not going to change the contents of this thing, so please pay attention to exactly where everything is".  And you'll see that now `headersWithIndex` is inferred as type `(readonly [string, number])[]`; that is, an array of [readonly tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) consisting of one `string` followed by one `number`.

And now the `Map` constructor is happy, since it knows for sure that each element of `headersWithIndex` is a pair of a `string` key and a `number` value, resulting in a `Map<string, number>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAD1QCgBYFMCGATLAJwGcAuRYqQmMAcwG0BdASkQG8BYAKEUQgUqJs+IsQDqMKBgCSYAskQBebr17CCJAHQBbHAAdMuDUoB8ieuqIAaRADkQ2gEZFDIrTXkB5YK43NmLADcKogA9KF8AlBCRqISUrLy5GiU1HSIAD6IYA7OhMxMTCGWJPEycljImnogxBho9ACMNgBEUADucC02AMytwHAghC1BYRFwANY4AJ7cAL7c3KCQsAh8hLhQWACy+t4AErEkACpwiZW+ouSpNAws5Lt6ADw3dDY5TkRmnDyRYIIlcSScryJQhNRHYg6fSXQimcwlGz2T6EWFQjyVbyw-yMRA4Yh-SjMYK-cKE6KAsrnZDJDb4BAAG2m5letHeuSILCKvw2UCGSDAWHaiEeaKpFWQxLGkxm8yAA)

Comment: Hey @jclaz great answer and thanks for the information about the error! Very helpful!